# Switch between ViewControllers using a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uiviewcontroller

I am very new to programming, especially iOS, so any answer should be given as if I am a baby with ADHD.

This is what I have in my `buttonclick`:

```
ItemCreateViewController *itemCreateViewConrtoller = [[ItemCreateViewController alloc] init];


[[self navigationController] pushViewController:itemCreateViewConrtoller animated:YES];
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So when you tap on that button, what exactly happens? And what is the issue?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's missing without any explanation of what you expect vs what's actually happening.

Comment: What you are missing is adding any content to the `ItemCreateViewController`.  How have you defined the content for your view controller? Are you using a nib/xib file or storyboards?  I realise that you could be defining your content programmatically, but as a newcomer this doesn't seem likely.  You need to use different methods of initialising the view controller depending on whether the content comes from a nib or storyboard

Comment: If you are so new then why not pushing views using storyboard instead?

Comment: When I tap the button on my "MainView" nothing happens. I want it to pull up the"ItemCreateViewController". I have three buttons: Add, Edit, Delete and a picker on "MainView". I want to be able to click add or edit to take me to the "ItemCreateView" in which there are 3 text boxes that I can add or edit items that will appear in the picker on "MainView"

Comment: "When I tap the button on my "MainView" nothing happens." Have you confirmed that the code you have shown is getting called?

Comment: I put an NSLog message after and it showed up

Comment: Please confirm - are you using a NIB file or a storyboard?

Comment: Sotyboard for "MainView" and .xib on my "ItemCreate"

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons why this could be happening among which is your button is not triggering  the intended action.  Among the reason why a button could not trigger is your XIB button is not connected to the button object defined in your header and method file.

If you look at the .h file look at all your IBOutlet items there should be a circle on the left most column if it is darkened out it is connected other wise it is not, and you need to connect this in your XIB file.

If this is not the problem please display the code where you specify the selector it should be something like this:

```
   [cancel_button addTarget:self action:@selector(Cancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Make sure that the selector is an IBAction function -

```
  -(IBAction)Cancel:(id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
return;
}
```

One other thing, any statement after pushViewController will get executed prior to any actual change in the view. The actual View change only happens once control is returned to IOS. This is significant if your push view controller command is within a long conditional process and you fail to code the return / exit properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a XIB file for your second view, you need to create it as follows -

```
ItemCreateViewController *itemCreateViewConrtoller = [[ItemCreateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ItemCreateViewController" bundle:nil];  //Ensure you use correct nib file name
```

Then you can push it

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:itemCreateViewConrtoller animated:YES];
```

But since you are using a Storyboard you could have just added the new view to your storyboard, linked the button to the new view with a "push" segue and everything would have been done for you.